# How to get image of qr-code after scanning in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, image, qr-code

I am developing a qr-code reader app in Xcode with swift. I scanned qr-code with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView: UIView?

    var scannerMetadataObj : AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject?

    @IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)

        guard let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first else {
            print("Failed to get the camera device")
            return
        }

        do {

            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            captureSession.addInput(input)

            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

        } catch {
            return
        }

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

        if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
            view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView)
        }


    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        captureSession.startRunning()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
    }

}


extension ScannerViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            return
        }


        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        scannerMetadataObj = metadataObj

        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        self.testImageView.image = // set image with qr-code
    }

}
```

after scanning qr-code, I want to get image of qr-code and set image of testImageView to obtained image. How it is possible? I am doing this because I want to save that image in database for future use. Here My only question is how to get image of qr-code from videoPreviewLayer and set image of testImageView to that image.

Comment: https://github.com/mahendragp/MGPBarcodeScanner

Comment: Mahendra GP, I am not using that library. I am doing it with classes provided by Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add AVCapturePhotoOutput and capturePhoto when needed.

1. Add two properties at ScannerViewController:

   ```
   private let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
   private var isCapturing = false
   ```
2. Add new output to captureSession at viewDidLoad:

   ```
   captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
   ```
3. Invoke capturePhoto at metadataOutput method and remember capturing state. Because metadataOutput method can be invoked very often:

   ```
   let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
   if !isCapturing {
       isCapturing = true
       photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
   }
   ```
4. Implement AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate protocol:

   ```
   extension ScannerViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
       func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
           isCapturing = false
           guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
               print("Error while generating image from photo capture data.");
               return
           }
           guard let qrImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
               print("Unable to generate UIImage from image data.");
               return
           }
           testImageView.image = qrImage
        }
   }
   ```
5. Also good idea to make some additional photo settings and error handling if needed.

Comment: I have found that this captures an image 5-10% of the time and the rest of the time gives me an error "The operation could not be completed".  Any thoughts, anyone?  TIA!